# Doesn't Exist/Access Permission Error when configuring Google Apps Marketplace SDK API

Tags: google-api, google-apps-marketplace

I am trying to configure the Google Apps Marketplace SDK and get the following error when clicking on the Configure Tab.

> **"The API "appsmarket-component.googleapis.com" doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it"**

However when I check for enabled services in the project it shows as enabled.

```
**$ gcloud service-management list --enabled
NAME                                 TITLE
appsmarket-component.googleapis.com  Google Apps Marketplace SDK**
```

Any pointers on how to resolve?

Note: I did setup the G-Suite account for the site just a couple of days back and so am still in the Trial period. Not sure if that has any impact on access to the API's?

Comment: Even I'm facing the same issue. Can anyone check for the same or it's a temporary issue?

Comment: I'm not having this issue.  i can configure and save the marketplace configuration without a problem.  I had issues a few weeks ago, when i got 500 errors on saving the config, but that problem is gone now.